# Read special characters in java

Tags: java, parsing, character-encoding, character

I have a question, I'm trying to read from a file, a set of key and value pairs ( Like a Dictionary). For this I'm using the following code:

```
 InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_BUNDLE);
     properties=new Hashtable();

     InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(is);
     LineReader lineReader=new LineReader(isr);
     try {
        while (lineReader.hasLine()) {
            String line=lineReader.readLine();
            if(line.length()>1 && line.substring(0,1).equals("#")) continue;
            if(line.indexOf("=")!=-1){
                String key=line.substring(0,line.indexOf("="));
                String value=line.substring(line.indexOf("=")+1,line.length());
                properties.put(key, value);
            }               
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the readLine function.

```
  public String readLine() throws IOException{
    int tmp;
    StringBuffer out=new StringBuffer();
    //Read in data
    while(true){
        //Check the bucket first. If empty read from the input stream
        if(bucket!=-1){
            tmp=bucket;
            bucket=-1;
        }else{
            tmp=in.read();
            if(tmp==-1)break;
        }
        //If new line, then discard it. If we get a \r, we need to look ahead so can use bucket
        if(tmp=='\r'){
            int nextChar=in.read();
            if(tmp!='\n')bucket=nextChar;//Ignores \r\n, but not \r\r
            break;
        }else if(tmp=='\n'){
            break;
        }else{
            //Otherwise just append the character
            out.append((char) tmp);
        }
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

Everything is fine, however I want it to be able to parse special characters. For example: ó that would be codified into \u00F3, however in this case it's not replacing it with the correct character... What would be the way to do it?

EDIT: Forgot to say that since I'm using JavaME the Properties class or anything similar does not exist, that's why it may seem that I'm reinventing the wheel...

Answer (score 2):

If it's encoded with UTF-16, can you not just 
`InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF16")`?

This would recognize your special characters right from the get-go and you wouldn't need to do any replacements.

Comment: Tried the following:  isr = new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF8"); however it didn't worked... have to mention that I'm working with JavaME

Comment: What is it encoded in? UTF8 or UTF16? Because UTF8 is similar to ASCII, and reading it in incorrectly will lose characters.

Comment: Add the output and any errors to your question so we can get a better idea of your problems

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that you character encoding is set in your InputStreamReader to be that of the file. If it doesn't match some characters can be incorrect.